# In grid view shortened String value

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

in my Flutter task app I have a grid view for my items, and if the text is long it shortens the String value. Any solution for a full-text view?

[image: App view]

Answer (score 1):

you should use [`auto_size_text`](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/),

```
AutoSizeText(
  'A really long String',
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
  minFontSize: 4,
  maxLines: 1,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Wrap your **Text Widget** with **FittedBox** and give maximum **width**.

Set **maxLines** to 1 in **Text** widget.

```
SizedBox(
      height: size.height * 0.1,
      width: size.width * 0.28,
      child: FittedBox(
        child: Text(
          "$number ",
          maxLines: 1,
          
        ),
      ),
    )
```